# What should I do if I move to another country?

Tags: ingress

I wanted to know if I should do something with my ingress account before moving to another country. I'm level 9 and I'm nearly 10, so I do not want to lose all my progress and I'm not sure if you can block me because my verification was carried out in the country where I am today.

Should I send an email to Niantic or do something similar, or can I just keep playing in my new home as I usually do?

Thank you and I hope you can help me.

Comment: Sorry my bad english, i used google translate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to do anything when you move to another country. This is the same as that you don't have to do anything when you travel abroad.

Your only possible problem would be the players in your new home who don't know you. It's obvious that you would get known in time and so this problem would be solved, too.

Comment: Thks Dude! So just lets play :D